# VB.NET Resolving XML aliases from inline schema

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm consuming a web service that provides XML data with an inline schema. It looks like XML output from Microsoft ADO. The schema contains the full attribute names, while the data itself only contains the aliases.

Sample XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xml xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" 
        xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" 
        xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" 
        xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
        <s:Schema id="RowsetSchema">
            <s:ElementType name="row" content="eltOnly">
                <s:AttributeType name="c4" rs:name="FULLNAME" rs:number="5" />
                <s:AttributeType name="c5" rs:name="FIRSTNAME" rs:number="6" />
                <s:AttributeType name="c6" rs:name="MIDDLENAME" rs:number="7" />
                <s:AttributeType name="c7" rs:name="LASTNAME" rs:number="8" />
                <s:AttributeType name="c8" rs:name="ADDRESSLINE1" rs:number="9" />
                <s:AttributeType name="c9" rs:name="ADDRESSLINE2" rs:number="10" />
                <s:AttributeType name="c10" rs:name="CITY" rs:number="11" />
                <s:AttributeType name="c11" rs:name="POSTALCODE" rs:number="12" />
                <s:AttributeType name="c12" rs:name="STATE" rs:number="13" />
            </s:ElementType>
        </s:Schema>
    <rs:data>
    <z:row c4="Jane Frickin Doe"
        c5="Jane"
        c6="Frickin"
        c7="Doe"
        c8="1234 Fifth Ave"
        c9=""
        c10="Anywhere"
        c11="98765"
        c12="US"/>
    </rs:data>
</xml>
```

I can pull this into an XDocument just fine and iterate through the records using:

```vb
For Each person In personRecs...<z:row>
    Dim firstName as String = person.@c5
Next
```

This presents problems, however, since the field order can change arbitrarily as fields are added or removed (first name could be @c6 if another field was added before it.) So how can I use `person.@FIRSTNAME` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the risk of stating the obvious -- and as a blast from the past for me :) -  since it is an actual ADO recordset xml, you can just push it into an ADO recordset and you will certainly have named field access.

You need a reference to the .net "ADODB" in the project.
And then you can have as the following:

```
    string strInputXML;
    strInputXML = string.Concat(
                            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>",
                            "<xml xmlns:s=\"uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882\" ",
                            "xmlns:dt=\"uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882\" ",
                            "xmlns:rs=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset\" ",
                            "xmlns:z=\"#RowsetSchema\">",
                            "<s:Schema id=\"RowsetSchema\">",
                            "    <s:ElementType name=\"row\" content=\"eltOnly\">",
                            "   <s:AttributeType name=\"c4\" rs:name=\"FULLNAME\" rs:number=\"5\" />",
                            "   <s:AttributeType name=\"c5\" rs:name=\"FIRSTNAME\" rs:number=\"6\" />",
                            "   <s:AttributeType name=\"c6\" rs:name=\"MIDDLENAME\" rs:number=\"7\" />",
                            "   <s:AttributeType name=\"c7\" rs:name=\"LASTNAME\" rs:number=\"8\" />",
                            "   <s:AttributeType name=\"c8\" rs:name=\"ADDRESSLINE1\" rs:number=\"9\" />",
                            "   <s:AttributeType name=\"c9\" rs:name=\"ADDRESSLINE2\" rs:number=\"10\" />",
                            "   <s:AttributeType name=\"c10\" rs:name=\"CITY\" rs:number=\"11\" />",
                            "   <s:AttributeType name=\"c11\" rs:name=\"POSTALCODE\" rs:number=\"12\" />",
                            "   <s:AttributeType name=\"c12\" rs:name=\"STATE\" rs:number=\"13\" />",
                            "    </s:ElementType>",
                            "</s:Schema>",
                            "<rs:data>",
                            "<z:row c4=\"Jane Frickin Doe\"",
                            " c5=\"Jane\"",
                            " c6=\"Frickin\"",
                            " c7=\"Doe\"",
                            " c8=\"1234 Fifth Ave\"",
                            " c9=\"\"",
                            " c10=\"Anywhere\"",
                            " c11=\"98765\"",
                            " c12=\"US\"/>",
                            "</rs:data>",
                            "</xml>"
                            );
    //--- interestingly, you have to drop the xml declaration
            // I'll be lazy and cut it as a string for this example
    strInputXML = strInputXML.Replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>", "");

    //--- And we can load an actual ADODB.recordset with it, for named field access
    ADODB.Stream objADOStream = new ADODB.Stream();
    objADOStream.Open();
    objADOStream.WriteText(strInputXML);
    objADOStream.Position = 0;
    ADODB.Recordset objRS = new ADODB.Recordset();
    objRS.Open(objADOStream);

    Console.WriteLine (objRS.Fields["FULLNAME"].Value);
```

Comment: PERFECT!! Thank you!! And to drop that first line, I just changed your WriteText line to `objADOStream.WriteText(strInputXML.Substring(strInputXML.IndexOf(">") + 1))`

Comment: Great!  Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you access the schema programmatically?  That is, read through it like you would any other part of the XML document?

I'd read in the schema and build a `Dictionary<string, string>` to map the field names (FIRSTNAME, etc.) to the tags (C4-C12), and looking up the tag name by field name.

My VB is rusty, but I could give you some example code in C# if you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name of the attribute for the FIRSTNAME like this:

```
Dim firstNameAttributeName As String = (
    From attr 
    In doc...<s:AttributeType> 
    Where attr.@rs:name = "FIRSTNAME" 
    Select attr.@name
    ).First()
```

(Where `doc` is your `XDocument` object)  Then, you can get the value of that attribute on any given element like this:

```
Dim personName As String = person.Attribute(firstNameAttributeName).Value
```

(Where `person` is the `XElement` object)  Doing so, obviously, requires the following `Imports`:

```
Imports <xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882">
Imports <xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset">
Imports <xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
```